# dealing with '#' symbol in the filepath

Tags: wget

I need to download some tif files from the link: http://ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17#data-product

I stored the path and file names in a text file in wget directory but the data is not getting downloaded correctly. I believe '#' symbol in the filepath is the issue.

for example keeping: http://ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17#data-product/MOD17A2_GPP.2008.M02.tif in a text file (temp.txt) and then giving command: wget -i temp.txt is not downloading the desired file correctly. Please help me with this issue. I tried backslash symbol as '#' but it doesn't work either.

the above weblink doesn't change when I browse through the folders, the sub-folder where desired tif files are kept can be reached by following path.
 /pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD17/GeoTIFF/Monthly_MOD17A2/GeoTIFF_0.05degree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '#' does pose some interesting issues in that one has to be careful to quote it with a backslash, or surrounding '...' or "...".  Let's see what happens.  Another issue is that the "#..." syntax is special in URLs, and isn't part of the underlying file name on the webserver.

```
wget -nd -np -nH 'http://ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17#data-product/MOD17A2_GPP.2008.M02.tif' -O temp.txt
```

The `temp.txt` file is present, but there's no base path specific, so virtually all the URLs are going to attempt to hit the local filesystem with a too-naïve command - we'll need to use `--base=http://ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17`

```
wget -nd -np -nH --base=http://ntsg.umt.edu/project/mod17 --force-html --input-file temp.txt
```

This downloads scads of files referenced by the original mod17 document, but almost certainly isn't really what you're looking for.

From your question, it looks like you're looking for a single file you found in the "Data Product" section, and needed to get the URL not by copying the location bar, but by right-mouse-clicking (in Firefox, for example) on the file you wanted and using "Copy Link Location".  Pasting the result somewhere should give you the string you need to provide to `wget`.  The same approach lets you right-click on the "Up to higher level directory" links to acquire their location, then potentially use wget's recursive fetch feature for the content inside them.

Good luck.

Comment: you are right, copying link location serves my purpose. Must say, you have great skills to apply fundamental concepts in this field. thanks.